# How do I set Titanfall in-game language to English (Russian version)?

Tags: origin, titanfall

*This question was initially about **Russian PC version** of Titanfall, available in Russian Origin store.*

*It appears that there exists a **Worldwide PC version** of Titanfall for which [Origin has posted a way to change language](http://help.ea.com/en/article/how-to-change-your-titanfall-game-language/).*

*Tech support said that Russian users can only buy Russian version of Titanfall (both normal and Deluxe editions) and that they will not have any other in-game language available. They also offered me a refund, which I accepted.*

---

I'm living in Russia and I recently pre-purchased Titanfall from here. My version doesn't have an option to select game language other than Russian.

Russian version has awful localization, many mistranslated technicalities and poorer game UI fonts than its English counterpart. Titan's on-board AI voice is pretty lame. The campaign briefing lines are cut off to fit the English files' length. Voice actors took liberty to change a few things to their liking. Audio effects like reverberation, echo and such are distinctively more basic. Overall audio quality is much lower, which greatly hinders immersion.

When I was playing open beta, it was all in English and considerably better. The game also doesn't support Russian characters so everyone is using transliteration in chat.

Switching Origin UI language to English didn't change the game's language. It's still all Russian.

How do I change Titanfall UI and audio to English?

---

Also: the support person didn't explicitly say tampering with localization files was against any rules or policy, so this may or may not be okay to do. Gotta find some hard info on that.

Although, adding launch parameters `-language english`, `-language "english"` in case of Russian version does not help. Players with **other versions** report that it **does help**.

As can be seen during game installation, the sound files alone take up about ~33 GB of disk space, and according to Origin's solution to Worldwide PC version, these files contain localization for every language available. It's just the rights to access them depend on version.

---

Note: it's important that the solution does not break any rules and is not outright illegal. Otherwise it may be removed from this site by a moderator, or, in worst case scenario, lead to some player's game and account being locked. So if you post something suspicious looking, be sure to include some links to official statements that allow such actions.

Comment: Most Russian localizations are done by like 6 different voice actors. I already know them by name, this isn't fun!

Comment: I don't want to disappoint you and can't say for sure, but very often games bought in Russia are locked to that region and language (for example Battlefield series). This is to discourage non-russian players from taking advantage of the often much cheaper russian licenses.

Comment: Looking in the game files, I found a GameInfo.txt in which we can read that : For example: `c:\hl2\cstrike` on a french machine would get a `c:\hl2\cstrike_french` path added to it. Which basically means that the language is selected automatically. I tried changing origin language but it doesn't work. So I'm currently loading a new language pack (english) for Windows in order the change the system language. We'll see if that works.

Comment: So I've tried different GDF binaries (`en_US` and `zh_TW`) with reg tweaks, and tried replacing the client with full `zh_TW` client, it still starts in full Russian, so it's likely that it stores it's locale somewhere outside of the registry or it's hidden somehow. Also there's nothing of interest in My Documents and appdata). Also the game wont start if you change/rename/do something else to `*client_mp_*.vpk` files, so probably there's some check for that.

Comment: You're sort of asking for two different things now, and making an answer a moving target while you're at it.  You want to make the Russian version language English, which, as you've stated, is not supported.  So you'll need to do it in an unsupported way.  But you also want to ensure that it's an official way to do it, so you're not doing something that might get you banned.  You can't have it both ways; either you want English in an unsupported version, or you want Origin to support English in a Russian version.  One or the other has to give.

Answer (score 2):

So here is the solution.

1. Go in origin and right click on TitanFall
2. Click on "Game Properties..."
3. Add the following text to the Command Line Arguments : -language "english"

You are done!

It will not work in some country (Russia) in which changing language looks to be prohibited.

Comment: How is this "the solution" if it doesn't work in Russia, which is OP's country according to the question?

Comment: `+1` It did work for me in polish version

Comment: The title doesn't mention Russia, a lot of people will get here only looking on how to change it to english. Also, telling that there is no "legal" way to achieve it is kind of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like we need `GDFBinary_en_US(_64).dll` for language change since all voice and locale packs are already installed with game itself. Trying to find it on the net now but still no luck.
The change itself may be made similar to [this BF4 solution](http://www.crappy3.com/home/index/how-to-change-language-in-battlefield-4) I suppose (excluding language pack part since we have it).

Comment: I'm not sure BF players are safe with that solution in terms of EULA and other policies. Is there any official statement that this is allowed for BF at least?

Comment: @user1306322 - This question is about Titanfall not Battlefield

Comment: @Ramhound oh really? :)

Comment: @user1306322 You can't have it both ways; you want the game in English, but the Russian version doesn't support it.  That means you'll have to resort to unofficial methods to make it happen.

Comment: @user1306322 I don't think Ramhound noticed you were the one who asked the initial question lol I liked your sarcasim btw made me lol for real

Comment: Don't think the GDF binary has any influence on this, since it should only provide some metadata for Windows' Games Library.

Comment: This file seems to have nothing to do with game language itself... I got polish version and adding `-language english` parameter to command line works. Don't have english GDFBinary file, only this: `GDFBinary_pl_PL_64.dll`

Answer (score -1):

-languange english in the parameters, worked for me.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Which parameters? Are you talking about launching the game with `-language english` as parameters to the executable?

Comment: Which parameters? Origin or Titanfall? Please, explain with more details.

Comment: One of the edits to the question mentions that the OP tried this with no success prior to your answer.

Comment: @Batophobia I suspect he may have a different game version even, which allows other game languages, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @user1306322 most likely but if we already know the OP tried this with no success then I don't see how this is helpful

Comment: @Batophobia I am the one who OPs! This could be helpful to determine which versions have multiple languages available.

Comment: Go to the origin, left click on titanfall icon, game propreties, and type -language english.